# how to store encrypted file / bytes securely in client device

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile, encryption

A friend of mine as me this question and it struck me that I cannot find any possible definite solution to this, so I pass the question to the community of experts.

The goal: storing file / bytes securely so that only client code can decrypt the bytes and present it to the user.

Let me explain with an example. Imagine I am building a video player mobile app. Server sends the encrypted content to client; client stores the encrypted content to device; and when user wants to play the video, client code decrypts the encrypted bytes from device and render the video to user.

The problem is that to decrypt, I will need a key, and since I need the client to be able to decrypt, the client needs to hold the key. Having an encryption key on the client side is always not secure.

Common proposed solutions I have been reading is to tie the encryption key to user's login credentials which does not work in my case because I am not protecting user's data, but protecting data from anyone including the users themselves.

My take is that it is not possible to protect data perfectly. The possible is to make it hard for anyone to decrypt my data, but come to think of it, if at least one user can do it, the video will be distributed world wide and I might have to be responsible for that (when you deal with copyright, consequences are damning).
Please advise.

Comment: The only way you can achieve this goal is to not have data that anyone cares to hack access to... if no one tries to find it then it's highly secure. If the key is on the device or in the code (especially Android(Java), which is quite simple to reverse engineer) then someone truly wanting to find the decrypted data will do so.

Comment: This issue is a commonly voiced complaint. What we'd like to do is prepopulate the keychain with a key when the user gets the app, but this is not currently possible. You can use obfuscation code to make it hard but not impossible for hackers to find the key.

Comment: It's just the usual unsolvable DRM problem.